# Python "IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, variables

```
cN = 0
lN = 0

while currentCharNo < wordListLength[lN]:
    WordfromList = wordList[lN]
    CharList = []
    wordChar = WordfromList[cN]
    CharList.append(wordChar)
    charOfWordsList = []
    cN = cN + 1
    currentCharNo = currentCharNo + 1
```

I get the `IndexError: string index out of range` error for the line `wordChar = WordfromList[cN]`. I really don't understand it, as it seems to be perfectly correct syntax to me.

Thank you!

Comment: nothing to do with syntax. it's just because `len(WordfromList)>=cN`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Do you mean `<=` ?

Comment: I don't understand this. Let's say `WordfromList = "apple"`. Then, because `cN = 0`, shouldn't `WordfromList[cN`] just return `a`?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, that wouldn't make sense either, because `cN = 0`. The length of `WordfromList` can't be less than 0.

Comment: @AKMan6: Yes it should, but value of `cN` is incrementing in `while currentCharNo < wordListLength[lN]`. Probably your while condition is wrong `wordListLength[lN]`. What value `wordListLength` is holding, we do not know that so we can't comment. You should put `print` statements and debug what is going wrong

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri yes, of course. thanks.

Comment: @AKMan6 It perfectly makes sense based on your code. How are you so sure that `cN` holds `0`? If `cN` is `0` and you are still getting error, that means `WordfromList` is empty

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, After some troubleshooting I've realized you are correct. In the full code, this while loop runs multiple times for different words in a list. I realized that at the end of each loop, I never set `cN` back to 0, so it kept incrementing past the length of the next word. Thanks you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

wordListLength[lN] returns the length of the list.
Say your list is 5 elements long.  So wordListLength[lN] = 5
When you index in the next command, you need to start at 0.
So the range you need to use is 0 to 4, not 1 to 5.

Comment: `wordListLength[lN] returns the length of the list.` - no, it does not. If you want the length of a list you would use `len(the_list)`